# decision tree using user defined split function in rpart: No splits returned when tree is run

Tags: cart, rpart

I've written a user defined splitting function to use with rpart, its returning a 'vector of goodness', but the tree that is returned never has any splits, just one node.

using the anova method on the same data provides a tree with many nodes.

I've been interrogating the code, but rpart feels like a black box so far, I can't figure out why there wouldn't be any splits or how to trouble shoot the problem.

Not sure whether this belongs here or @stackoverflow.  I'll include my function

```
distance <- function(y, wt, x, parms, continuous) {
    # return a vector of goodness using a distance measure
    # find distance between treatment and control in left and right,
    # gain = difference between the two, normalized 

    if (missing(parms) || is.null(parms['treated']))
        stop("requires vector indicating treatment")
    treated <- which(parms['treated'] == max(parms['treated']))
    #treated <- which(parms$treated == max(parms$treated))

    goodness <- numeric(length(x) - 1)

    for (i in 1:(length(x)-1)) {
        left <- which(x >= x[i])
        left.data <- y[left]
        right.data <- y[-left]

        left.distance <- dist(rbind(left.data[treated], left.data[-treated])) 
        right.distance <- dist(rbind(right.data[treated], right.data[-treated]))  

        treated.frac <- length(left.data[treated])/length(left)

        normalization <- gini(c(treated.frac, 1-treated.frac)) * left.distance
        + treated.frac * gini(left.data[treated])
        + (1 - treated.frac) * gini(left.data[-treated]) + .5

        goodness[i] <- (left.distance - right.distance)/normalization
    }
    list(goodness = goodness, direction=rep(1, length(x) - 1))
}
```

Comment: I think the direction is wrong

Comment: This is a very old question but thought I would comment as I ran into this problem and resolved it (for my use case). I also thought that my trees were not growing due to an issue in my `splitting` function. It turns out that I could verify, via debug, that my split function calculated goodness of splits correctly and that `rpart` used the best split each time. The issue was to do with the `evaluation` function.

Comment: @Alex - so could you update the answer?

Comment: @EngrStudent I do not know what answer your are referring to. Answering this question is possibly on my list of things to do but it is low priority for me as I will need to create data and replicate the problem.